# Prove that a function between surfaces that preserves inner distances is an isometry

Tags: riemannian-geometry, surfaces, curves, isometry

We define an isometry as a bijection between surfaces whose differential is a linear isometry between tangents. I've read that this definition is equivalent to the following: $f$ preserves the inner distance between two points, i.e. the infimum of the length of the piecewise $C^1([0,1])$ curves that join them, where $$L(\gamma)=\int_0^1||\gamma'(t)||\ dt$$

I know that, using an approximation theorem by Whitney, the piecewise $C^1$ condition can be restricted to $C^\infty$. Also, we can use geodesics, which are always $C^\infty$. But also using geodesics I have some problems in proving that the definition "preserving distances" implies the definition "the differential is a linear isometry between tangents".

P.S. And in generic Riemannian manifolds? Is this true (I suppose it is; I know that the converse is true: an isometry in the "tangent" sense sends geodesics in geodesics, and preserves their length)? And how can it be proved?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is true for Riemannian manifolds of arbitrary dimension that a distance-preserving bijection is a Riemannian isometry. This is known as the [Myers–Steenrod theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myers%E2%80%93Steenrod_theorem). Proofs are somewhat complicated. Start by reading the Palais' paper mentioned in the wikipedia article.